# Adding multiple animated sprites on canvas make the game FPS drop sharply

Tags: javascript, html5, html-canvas

I am using PIXI.js to build a html5 canvas game. Although this is PIXI.js specific question I think this may happen very often in HTML5 canvas games.

I have placed hundreds of static sprites in my game and all goes well. But when I try to add 30 animated sprites (AI players) in the game, the FPS drops from 60 to 30. If I add even more it becomes very slow and unplayable. I have profiled my program on Chrome and found that this method

`CanvasSpriteRenderer.prototype.render`

is using too many CPU resources. Is there a way to reduce the CPU consumption and make my game smooth again?

Comment: Do you use spritesheets or gifs?

Comment: No I only draw the canvas object as texture onto a sprite.

Comment: but how do you store the sprite textures?

Comment: @Bálint PIXI.js creates the sprite from a texture which is created from a HTMLCanvasElement. So I think the texture is stored in sprites? I don't know how this is done in detail but the texture is pre-created. In the update loop I just use `renderer.render(stage)` to show everything on stage.